# Counting number of occurrences of a value resulting in "Mismatched Input" error?

Tags: sql, count, azure-databricks

So, I have a table where a bunch of people took multiple surveys. Each survey had a rating out of 10. I need to find the average per survey (which I've already done) and also the number of 10s that each survey received.

Below is the code I thought would work:

```
SELECT person, survey, AVG(rating), COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 10) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY person, survey
```

The error that I get is: mismatched input 'WHEN' expecting {')', ','}

Not sure where I've gone wrong. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is there no indication as to which line position the characters are mismatched? Look around your editor it usually says something like line **i** position **j** ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CASE` expression in your call to `COUNT` is incomplete.  Use this version:

```
SELECT
    person,
    survey,
    AVG(rating) AS avg_rating,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rating = 10 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM Table
GROUP BY
    person,
    survey;
```

The `COUNT()` will count 1 for every record having a 10 rating, otherwise it will count `NULL`, which just gets ignored.

Note that on some databases, such as MySQL or Postgres, you may actually sum a direct boolean expression:

```
SUM(rating = 10)
```

But the longer version above should work on pretty much any database.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick help.